# Как добавить в хеш виде геометрию Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, geojson, postgis

Нужно геометрию добавить в хеш виде, в поле geometry с типом geometry, при запросе `UPDATE geo SET geometry = ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-126,48),4326)) WHERE options->>'koatuu' =  '0110391818' ;`

Вот такие ошибки

> > ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
> >
> > > HINT:  "c0" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry

Было сделано по примеру из оф сайта PostGis

```
SELECT ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-126,48),4326));
           st_geohash
      ----------------------
          c0w3hf1s70w3hf1s70w3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему вы хотите в `geometry` записать не предназначенный для того результат `ST_GeoHash`?

Как говорит [вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash),

> Geohash is a public domain geocoding system invented by Gustavo Niemeyer[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), which encodes a geographic location into a short string of letters and digits.

Вы можете `geohash` преобразовать до `geometry` вызовом [`ST_GeomFromGeoHash`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoHash.html), но зачем вам писать `geohash` там где вы сказали, что будете хранить `geometry`?

Comment: а какой хеш можно хранить в таком поле?

Comment: зачем вам какой-то хэш? У вас уже есть geometry поле и функции возвращающие именно geometry данные. И функции обработки geometry типа.

Comment: подскажите еще, пожалуйста как работать с polygon ? а именно если у меня массив с массивами, в которых lon и lat, какую функцию выбрать?

Comment: задайте лучше отдельный вопрос с описанием что есть и что надо получить.